# getting all attribute values of spans inside a div

Tags: ajax, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I have a div and inside of this, there are a lot of spans as follows:

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <span id="first_id" itemindex="0">first span</span>
    <span id="second_id" itemindex="1">second span</span>
    <span id="third_id" itemindex="2">third span</span>
    ...
</div>
```

I want to define the function "getItemIndexValues()" in JQuery who get all values in "myDiv". It is possible?

Comment: What from your examples are the values of the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to be using [`data-` prefixed attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/).

HTML:

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <span id="first_id" data-itemindex="0">first span</span>
    <span id="second_id" data-itemindex="1">second span</span>
    <span id="third_id" data-itemindex="2">third span</span>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var arr = $( 'span', '#mydiv' ).map( function () {
    return $( this ).data( 'itemindex' );
}).get();
```

Here, `arr` will be `[ '0', '1', '2' ]`

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/fQJAk/

Btw, if you prefer an array of numbers, do this:

```
return +$( this ).data( 'itemindex' );
-------^
```

Comment: Interesting. How does `+` work like that? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: @gideon It's the unary plus operator. It performs conversion to Number. Speced here: http://es5.github.com/#x11.4.6

Answer (score 0):

I didn't verified it but I think this should work:

```
$("#mydiv>span").each(function(a,b){
    alert($(b).attr('itemindex'));
});
```

By using the child selector here: http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/